# Error when running "pod install" in terminal -> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseAppCheck"

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, cocoa

Full error message:

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseAppCheck":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseAppCheck (= 10.3.0, ~> 10.3.0-beta)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_app_check (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_app_check/ios`) was resolved to 0.1.2-2, which depends on
      FirebaseAppCheck (~> 10.7.0-beta)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `FirebaseAppCheck` inside your development pod `firebase_app_check`.
   You should run `pod update FirebaseAppCheck` to apply changes you've made.
```

I recently upgraded my flutter version and now I can no longer run "pod install".

What I've tried:

pod deintegrate -> pod install -> pod update

pod install --repo-update

pod repo update

pod update FirebaseAppCheck

remove Podfile.lock -> pod install

Updated platform :iOS '12.0' to platform :iOS '16.0'

flutter clean, restart Mac, clear cache, etc.

pod update -> pod install .. this worked and let me run pod install without any errors but when trying to archive the build in Xcode, I get a different error.

Added: $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.3.0' .. this worked and let me run pod install without any errors but when trying to archive the build in Xcode, I get a different error.

More details can be shared on those other two errors but I think the real problem is with the error I shared here (version compatibility of dependencies).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: can remove these files in ios folder - .symlinks, pods and podfile.lock. 
then execute pod install --repo-update command

Comment: have you tried "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions" ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but still no luck on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this error. Stupid mistake on my end, I had upgraded flutter version on Windows but not on my Mac. When I cloned the GitHub repo on my Mac, and ran "pod install", that's when the error occurred. After upgrading flutter on my Mac and running "pod install", no more errors.